# Regarding Espace Etale of a presheaf, is $\bar s$ an open map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry.
In the exercise 1.13 of II on page 67, given a presheaf $\mathscr F $ on $X$ , $s \in \mathscr F (U)$, $\bar s : U\to Spe(\mathscr F)$ is defined by $P \to s_P$, its germ at $P$.
We make $Spe(\mathscr F)$ into a topological space by giving it the strongest topology such that all the maps $\bar s : U\to Spe(\mathscr F)$ for all $U$, and all $s \in \mathscr F (U)$, are continuous. 
I wonder whether $\bar s$ is an open map. 
I have proved it is true. 
It suffices to show that $\bar s (U)$ is open.
For any  $\bar t : V\to Spe(\mathscr F)$,
if $\bar t ^{-1} (\bar s (U))$ is open then it is proved by the definition of strong topology.
$$
P \in \bar t ^{-1} (\bar s (U)) \\
\iff \bar t(P) \in \bar s(U) \\
\iff \bar t(P) = \bar s (P) \\
\iff \langle V,t\rangle_P=\langle U,s\rangle_P \\
\iff \exists W \subset U\cap V \quad \text{s.t} \quad t|_W=s|_W  \\
\iff \forall Q\in W , \bar t(Q)=\bar s(Q) \\
\iff P\in W \subset  \bar t ^{-1} (\bar s (U))
$$ 
Thus $\bar t ^{-1} (\bar s (U))$ is open and so $\bar s$ is an open map. 
But I am not convinced this result since Hartshorne doesn't refer to this and it looks like very strong result.
Is it right $\bar s$ is an open map? If not point out my mistake please.

Comment: Yes, sections of espaces étalés are always open embeddings.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for your help. I have learned more thanks to you.

Comment: I think the third equivalence might be wrong since we don’t know what $s$ is from $\bar{s}$.